# Spring Batch Remote Partitioning with Kafka as middle wear

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I was checking Spring batch remote partitioning for loading data from RDBMS sources as well as multi partitioned Kafka topic. Problem with me is, I can not have rabbitMQ or JMS as the middle wear between master and worker nodes, I can only have Kafka as channel between the master and worker.

On all the documentation I can see that it supports JMS and AMQP.
Can anyone tell me how we can use remote partitioning with Kafka as middle wear .... if anyone has working example also, it will be a great help?

Comment: Were u able to use kafka as middleware? If yes, can u pls share some example impl?

Comment: yes i was able to use ... but i don't have that code with me now

Answer (score 0):

`spring-integration-kafka` provides [similar endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#spring-integration) to those used for JMS and RabbitMQ so it shouldn't be difficult to apply the concepts in that documentation to kafka.

The `spring-integration-kafka` latest version is 3.3.1 (it is moving to the core spring-integration project in 5.4.0).